# multilevel logistic regression via maximum likelihood in R

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, likelihood

I want to develop a mixed effect logistic regression in R using likelihood function and compare the results (estimated parameters) with the output of glmer function. I couldn't find a good material for the likelihood formulation. So, just explain my panel dataset and put the code I have written for simple logistic regression. My panel dataset is "try" and the response variable is "happy" which is binary and has two levels (yes=1 or No=0). I have started with adding one independent variable (x) to model. I have ïd" column in my data which shows the observations who belong to same individual (observations are nested within individuals).  Here is the code for binary logit model without random effect. How can I add random effect for id column to my code and get same results as glmer gives.
my data is something like:

| happy | x | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |

```
'LL<-function(b_00,b_11,b_22){
     data<- try%>%mutate(p=1/(1+exp(-b_00-b_11*x)))
     data<-data%>%mutate(loglik=happy*log(p)+(1-happy)*log(1-p))
     return(-sum(data$loglik))}'
```

I want to write the code with same results as below function:

```
model = glmer(happy~x+ (1 |id), 
          data=try, family = binomial)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference Ben. I have done this for continuous response variable and got same results as lmer function. Just want to add random error to the likelihood function and give the likelihood to a optim() to get the results

Answer (score 2):

Unlike for linear mixed models, the likelihood doesn't collapse to a penalized sum of squares that can be computed by closed-form linear algebra. The details of `glmer`'s algorithms are described in [this incomplete manuscript](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/www/JSS/glmer.pdf?root=lme4) (it builds on the 2015 Bates et al. *J. Stat. Software* paper, which you may need to read for some of the notation).

The implementation of the likelihood involves a *penalized iteratively reweighted least squares* (PIRLS) step (described in the manuscript linked above), which has been implemented by Steve Walker in pure R [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4pureR/blob/master/R/pirls.R); that will be easier than reading the C++ code in the `lme4` package ...